# Как заполнить button grid'ом из кода и заполнить его textblock'ами?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

У меня создаются кнопки в окне cs приложения WPF. Я хочу взять одну из кнопок и заполнить ее одной буквой, но чтобы в правом верхнем еще был маленький значок *3. Для этого заполняю кнопку grid и в этот grid помещаю 2 текстблока соответственно с строками столбцами

```
Grid _gridforbutton = new Grid();
        TextBlock _double = new TextBlock();
        _double.Text = "*3";
        _double.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        _double.FontSize = 5;


        TextBlock _word = new TextBlock();
        _word.Text = letter;
        _word.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        _word.FontSize = 30;
        _gridforbutton.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(5) });
        _gridforbutton.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(25) });
        _gridforbutton.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(5) });
        _gridforbutton.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(25) });
        _gridforbutton.Children.Add(_double);
        Grid.SetRow(_double, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(_double, 1);
        _gridforbutton.Children.Add(_word);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(_word, 2);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(_word, 2);
        btn1.Content = _gridforbutton;
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу сделать так, будто буква заполняет всю кнопку, а значок *3 в правом крайнем углу как будто добавлен. Но в итоге *3 располагается сверху а кнопку почему-то не видно полностью

[image: Кнопка не должна выглядеть именно так, но суть в этом: буква на весь экран и в углу маленькая надпись *3/*2 lheujuj цвета]

Comment: Вы знаете, что элементы через код создавать не есть хорошо?

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста скрин того, что вы хотите. Как будет время, попробую накидать примерчик (если не опередят).

Answer (score 3):

И так, посмотрим на вашу задачу, что требуется? А требуется нам некая кнопка, которая будет иметь дополнительные значения, иметь свой стиль и все это должно быть удобно! Для таких целей можно использовать UserControl. Давайте сделаем подобный:

- Жмем по нашему проекту правой кнопкой мыши - Добавить - Пользовательский элемент управления - Думаем над именем и жмем Ок.
- Далее у нас будет почти все тоже самое, что и у обычного окна (.xaml файл и рядом .cs файл).
- В .cs файл нам надо задать DependencyProperty на все доп свойства нашего контрола, пишем и получаем что то вроде этого:

  ```
  public partial class CustomButton : UserControl
  {
      public CustomButton()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      public Visibility DoubleVisibility
      {
          get => (Visibility)GetValue(DoubleVisibilityProperty);
          set => SetValue(DoubleVisibilityProperty, value);
      }

      public Brush DoubleBackground
      {
          get => (Brush)GetValue(DoubleBackgroundProperty);
          set => SetValue(DoubleBackgroundProperty, value);
      }

      public Brush DoubleForeground
      {
          get => (Brush)GetValue(DoubleForegroundProperty);
          set => SetValue(DoubleForegroundProperty, value);
      }

      public string DoubleText
      {
          get => (string)GetValue(DoubleTextProperty);
          set => SetValue(DoubleTextProperty, value);
      }

      public string Text
      {
          get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
          set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
      }

      public ICommand ButtonCommand
      {
          get => (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty);
          set => SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value);
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleVisibilityProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DoubleVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleBackgroundProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DoubleBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 252, 74, 38))));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleForegroundProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DoubleForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleTextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DoubleText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata("0"));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata("Text"));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
  }
  ```
- Отлично! Теперь нужно сделать вид нашего контрола. Так, как нам требуется кнопка, то давайте перепишем ей дизайн:

  ```
  <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, ElementName=Control}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
      <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.Effect>
                      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="-90" Opacity="0.5"/>
                  </Grid.Effect>
                  <Border Name="Mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="7" Margin="5"/>
                  <Border Background="White" Margin="5">
                      <Border.OpacityMask>
                          <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
                      </Border.OpacityMask>
                      <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <ColumnDefinition/>
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <Grid Visibility="{Binding DoubleVisibility, ElementName=Control, FallbackValue=Visible, TargetNullValue=Visible}">
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                              <Grid>
                                  <Polygon Points="100,0, 0,100 0,0"
                                               Fill="{Binding DoubleBackground, ElementName=Control, FallbackValue=#FC4A26, TargetNullValue=#FC4A26}"
                                               Stretch="Uniform"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                  <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                      <TextBlock Padding="5,5,25,0"
                                                     Text="{Binding DoubleText, ElementName=Control, StringFormat=x{0}, FallbackValue=x0, TargetNullValue=x0}" 
                                                     Foreground="{Binding DoubleForeground, ElementName=Control, FallbackValue=White, TargetNullValue=White}"/>
                                  </Viewbox>
                              </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                          <Viewbox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                              <TextBlock Margin="10" Foreground="#4d4d4d"
                                                     Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Control, FallbackValue=Text, TargetNullValue=Text}" 
                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                          </Viewbox>
                      </Grid>
                  </Border>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
  </Button>
  ```
- Самому UserControl задаем свойством его имя:

  ```
  Name="Control"
  ```
- Ну что, это уже как минимум втрое облегчит вашу задачу (а может даже и решит ее), ведь у вас уже готовый контрол и вместо редактирования кнопки через код, вы можете сразу вызвать этот самый контрол, задав ему все необходимые значения.

---

Но! Я не устану повторять, что создавать объекты через код не верный подход! WPF это не WinForms, тут есть очень замечательная вещь - Binding. А отличным помощником для этих всех привязок является MVVM паттерн, а у него есть очень забавное правило - "Код не должен знать о View (xaml разметке)".

Давайте я покажу простейшую реализацию MVVM, где мы будет выводить несколько созданных нами кнопок:

- Нам потребуется пару классов для команд:

  ```
  public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
  {
      private Action<T> action;
      public RelayCommand(Action<T> action) => this.action = action;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      #pragma warning disable CS0067
      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      #pragma warning restore CS0067
      public void Execute(object parameter) => action((T)parameter);
  }

  public class RelayCommand : ICommand
  {
      private Action action;
      public RelayCommand(Action action) => this.action = action;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      #pragma warning disable CS0067
      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      #pragma warning restore CS0067
      public void Execute(object parameter) => action();
  }
  ```
- Далее нам нужен класс, который будет описывать свойства нашей кнопки:

  ```
  public class ButtonViewModel
  {
      public Visibility DoubleVisibility { get; set; }
      public Brush DoubleBackground { get; set; }
      public Brush DoubleForeground { get; set; }
      public string DoubleText { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
      public ICommand Command { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Теперь нам нужно сделать основной класс, который будет задан как DataContext, некий MainViewModel. В нем создадим коллекцию, заполним ее и сделаем обработчик наших кнопок:

  ```
  public class MainViewModel
  {
      public ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel> Buttons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel>();

      public MainViewModel()
      {
          Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel
          {
              Text = "A",
              DoubleText = "2",
              DoubleVisibility = Visibility.Visible,
              DoubleBackground = Brushes.Green,
              Command = new RelayCommand<ButtonViewModel>(Clicked)
          });

          Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel
          {
              Text = "B",
              DoubleText = "10",
              DoubleVisibility = Visibility.Visible,
              Command = new RelayCommand<ButtonViewModel>(Clicked)
          });

          Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel
          {
              Text = "C",
              DoubleVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed,
              Command = new RelayCommand<ButtonViewModel>(Clicked)
          });
      }


      void Clicked(ButtonViewModel obj)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Кнопка {obj.Text} нажата!");
      }
  }
  ```
- Привяжем все это дело:

  ```
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = MainViewModel;
  }
  ```
- Ну и последнее, создаем View для этого всего. Для этого классно подходит ItemsControl:

  ```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <local:CustomButton Width="150" Height="150"
                                  ButtonCommand="{Binding Command}" 
                                  Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                  DoubleVisibility="{Binding DoubleVisibility}"
                                  DoubleBackground="{Binding DoubleBackground}"
                                  DoubleForeground="{Binding DoubleForeground}"
                                  DoubleText="{Binding DoubleText}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
  ```
- Фух, ну все, время запускать и любоваться результатом:

[image: Result]

Ну, на этом все, надеюсь я показал вам правильную работу с элементами в WPF. Удачного изучения!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ИльяЛоладзе Да на здоровье, надеюсь что смог наставить вас этим всем на путь истинный!