# Использование своего UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Создал свой User Control элемент.Расставил и настроил там элементы как они должны располагаться, растягиваться.Как мне создавать его программно с заданными параметрами(Изображение, текст) во время выполнения приложения? Чтобы внести больше ясности - этот User Control как обёртка.Я передаю лишь пару параметров, которые подставляются в Image и TextBlock.

Comment: Можете посмотреть данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553), я там делал что то подобное. Если быть точнее, то обернул Button в UserControl со своими свойствами и вывел его на экран путем привязки к коллекции с нужными мне свойствами.

Comment: Почитайте про свойства зависимости