# wpf user control, не работает триггер

Tags: c#, wpf

Я добавил к контролу свойство IsDropClose. При закрытии списка оно принимает значение true. Не могу разобраться, как указать триггер в другом стиле ComboBoxToggleButton. В этом стиле мне нужно при срабатывание триггера изменить цвет у arrow.
Пробовал так, но это не работает:

```xml
 <Trigger Property="local:CustomComboBox.IsDropClose" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="arrow" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
 </Trigger>
```

Код UserControl:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DELETEEE.CustomComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DELETEEE" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"  xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Name="CustComboBox">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:CustomComboBox x:Key="customComboBox"/>
        <!--Цвет фона Combobox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_ComboBox">#FFEF89E7</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет фона при наведение мыши на ComboBox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBox">Yellow</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет BorderBrush у Combobox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBorderBrush_ComboBox">#FF291E28</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет при нажатии\подстветки BorderBrush Combobox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBorderBrush_MouseOver_ComboBox">Blue</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет фона стрелочки у Combobox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_ComboBoxArrow">#BBBBBB</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет фона при наведение мыши на стрелочку ComboBox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxArrow">Blue</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет тени у выпадающей панели ComboBox-->

        <Color x:Key="ColorShadow_ComboBox">Black</Color>


        <!--Цвет при выборе Items ComboBox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_IsSelected_ComboBox">Green</SolidColorBrush>


        <!--Цвет при наведение на Items ComboBox-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxItem" Color="Gray"/>


        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>


        <!--Кнопка ComboBox-->

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" x:Name="Test" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" CornerRadius="20"  Background="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_ComboBox}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ColorBorderBrush_ComboBox}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                            <!--Отрисовка стрелочки-->

                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" Margin="0 0 10 0"  SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30">
                                <Viewbox x:Name="viewbox" Width="34" Height="34">
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M0.21967 1.28033C-0.0732236 0.987436 -0.073223 0.512563 0.21967 0.21967C0.512563 -0.0732233 0.987437 -0.0732233 1.28033 0.21967L6.21967 5.15901L11.159 0.21967C11.4519 -0.073223 11.9268 -0.0732232 12.2197 0.21967C12.5126 0.512563 12.5126 0.987437 12.2197 1.28033L7.11632 6.38368C6.62111 6.87889 5.81823 6.87889 5.32302 6.38368L0.21967 1.28033Z"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_ComboBoxArrow}">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform></RotateTransform>
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="local:CustomComboBox.IsDropClose" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--Тригер при наведение мыши на шапку ComboBox--><!--

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

                                --><!--Цвет при наведение на стрелочку--><!--

                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxArrow}"/>

                                --><!--Цвет при наведение на ComboBox--><!--

                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBox}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBorderBrush_MouseOver_ComboBox}"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            --><!--Тригер нажатия на стрелочку--><!--

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBorderBrush_MouseOver_ComboBox}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxArrow}"/>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="arrow">

                                            --><!--Отражение по вертикали <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"   To="-1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>--><!--

                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                          From="0"   To="180" Duration="0:0:00.500"></DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="arrow">

                                            --><!--Отражение по вертикали <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"   To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>--><!--

                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                          From="180"   To="360" Duration="0:0:00.500"></DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>-->
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                    <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>



        <!--Панель с контентом(Items) у Combobox-->

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                    <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="20" x:Name="dropDownBorder" Margin="2 10 2 2" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" >
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="0 10 0 0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="{DynamicResource ColorShadow_ComboBox}" Opacity="0.14" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="5"></DropShadowEffect>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                    </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual1">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


        <!--Список(Items) ComboBox-->

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual1}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_IsSelected_ComboBox}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_IsSelected_ComboBox}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_IsSelected_ComboBox}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxItem}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Visibility="Visible" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemContainerStyle1}" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0,0,65,145" DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed">
            <TextBlock>Text Text Text Text Text Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Код позади:

```
public partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl
{
    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDropCloseProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("IsDropClose", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomComboBox));

    public bool IsDropClose
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDropCloseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDropCloseProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsDropClose = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему юзерконтрол сам себе назначает `DataContext`? Путаница какая-то. Контекст он должен наследовать от родителя и привязки данных выполнять через него. Еще возможно вам нужна двухсторонняя привязка по умолчанию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280507/373567

Comment: @aepot  ```Почему юзерконтрол сам себе назначает DataContext? ``` какие то примеры с гугла пробовал, осталось. Много чего успел попробовать, код выложил как есть.

Comment: Не надо в юзерконтролах делать `DataContext = this`, если требуются бинды к себе или родителю, используйте `RelativeSource` с назначением `Self` или `AncestorType`, либо через `ElenentName`, если цель имеет `x:Name`.

Comment: @aepot понял, спасибо за пояснение) Еще `DataTrigger` переместил вниз по коду, так как когда он был сверху, то он не работал, видать анимации в wpf в очередь как то ставятся

Answer (score 0):

У меня отлично работает следующее. код позади контрола `.cs` в нем ничего не менял, нужно было только правильно указать привязку.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropClose, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomComboBox}}}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="arrow" Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue" />
 </DataTrigger>
```

теперь есть кастомный тригер который отвечает за зактрытие списка у combobox, по умолчанию его нету, подобных тригеров тоже нет. Что заставило изобретать велосипед

Comment: Обычно привязка к `DependencyProperty` выполняется через `Trigger`, а не `DataTrigger`. Но если это работает, то пусть будет так.

Comment: @aepot в `Trigger` надо писать Property, Если я напишу  ```<Trigger Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomComboBox}}, Path=IsDropDownClose}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" TargetName="arrow"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>```
То я получу ошибку ```System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Binding" невозможно задать в свойстве "Property" типа "Trigger". "Binding" можно задать только в параметре DependencyProperty объекта DependencyObject."```

Comment: @aepot через `DataTriger` или же `MultiDataTrigger` работает, а с `Triger` не стал разбираться