# Как изменить свойство стиля через Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть стиль

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="AuthTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="8"
                            Background="#3e4147">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                       x:Name="txt"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       Foreground="DarkGray">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=MessageBox}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

И в моем xaml документе есть

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
        Height="30"
        Width="230"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource AuthTextBox}"
        Text="Login">
 </TextBox>
```

Свойство Text в TextBox не работает и мой текст не выводится. Как мне написать в xaml, чтобы оно вывело текст?

Comment: Перед тем как что-либо менять, стоит зайти [в документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates) и увидеть там то, как устроен тот или иной компонент. Сделав это, вы увидите элемент с именем `PART_ContentHost`, который отвечает за отображение текста, собственно, где он у вас?

Comment: [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892926/220553) оставлю просто тут, на всякий...