# Как добавить в ListBox отдельно элемент, если у него уже определен ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Пытаюсь создать `ListBox` в котором первым элементом будет отдельная кнопка со своей командой, а после неё уже идти все остальные элементы из `ItemsSource` с общим оформлением. Выглядеть это должно примерно как-то так.
[image: Извиняюсь за своё творчество]

Получился вот такой `ListBox`

```
<ListBox
        Margin="0,87,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Divisions}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDivision}">
        <TextBlock
            Width="200"
            Height="50"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            Text="Add" />
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Width="90" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock
                        Width="200"
                        Height="50"
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Но при такой реализации он выдаёт:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в PresentationFramework.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Перед использованием свойства ItemsSource семейство Items должно быть пустым.

А как реализовать по другому понятия не имею.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы в `ListBox` внутрь добавляете `TextBlock`, что означает добавления нового Item'a в его коллекцию, а потом вы пытаетесь задать `ItemsSource` и тут у вас происходит конфликт, ибо `ListBox` не пустой, но и привязку сделать надо. Так что `TextBlock` тут явно лишний. `как реализовать по другому` - например [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553). То есть, сделайте `UserControl`-ы с нужным дизайном, создайте под них ViewModel, ну и связывайте все привязанной коллекцией.

Comment: перенести этот первый обязательный `<TextBlock ... Text="Add" />` в начало коллекции `Divisions`