# Свойства в Wpf не распознаются

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, usercontrol, property

### Проблема

Ничего не предвещало беды, но мне понадобилось создать свой контрол (неважно какой). Вот его примерный код (пока без свойств зависимости) (MyControl.xaml.cs):

```cs
...

namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 50;

        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот его использование в разметке (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ctrl:MyControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Но стоит мне только заменить строчку

```
<ctrl:MyControl/>
```

на

```
<ctrl:MyControl MyProperty="145"/>
```

то всё ломается и пишет: "Член "MyProperty" не распознан или недоступен".

---

Как это решить?

Comment: Если вы пишете `MyControl MyProperty`, то `MyProperty` должен быть типа `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я специально не юзал свойства зависимости: с ними тоже не работает с такими же "симптомами".

Comment: Значит вы что то делаете не так, верно? Посмотрите примеры того, как делать свои контролы, можете например глянуть [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553) вариант или любой другой.