# Вывод списка услуг, как на картинке, C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

проблема такова, будь я в вебе, я бы без проблем это сделал, но никак не приходит в голову, как мне циклом выводить с БД список услуг вёрсткой, как на картинке, направьте в нужную сторону пожалуйста:)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сами как пробовали? Ведь это базовая самая вещь в WPF. Делайте класс с нужными данными, свойство коллекции этого класса, привязывание к нему ItemsControl с нужным видом, да и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В том то и дело, что я не профессионал в WPF, поэтому и спросил, спасибо, буду копать в сторону ItemsControl

Comment: Не надо быть профессионалом, надо пытаться сначала делать самостоятельно, а уж потом спрашивать. Вот я сейчас уверен, что вы без труда сделаете сами, сами разберётесь. А если дать вам ответ, поймёте ли вы тему?

Comment: [Очень похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1120716/373567)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, получилось всё, теперь знаю об ItemsControlах)

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое за пример

Comment: @VladislavVelikoivanenko Я и не сомневался. Удачи! В следующий раз пробуйте сделать сами, это очень просто и если уж сильно застрянете, то приходите сюда.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ проблема в том ещё, что я не нашёл нигде как отлавливать выбранный элемент, у меня же каждую услугу можно редактировать при нажатии на кнопку и удалять, так вот как при нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать" Открывались данные именно того элемента, на котором я нажал эту кнопку?

Comment: Делаете главный класс, который содержит в себе свойство команды (`ICommand`) и метод, который надо выполнить. Задаете этот класс, как `DataContext`, ну и [привязываете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понял, спасибо огромное, буду пробовать

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Просто с MVVM у меня слабо, а все примеры, которые я нашёл в интернете, слишком навороченные, я не могу там понять что за что отвечает, может посоветуете где посмотреть инфу?

Comment: Да примеров полно, можете посмотреть все мои ответы по MVVM (найдете думаю через поиск), пытался везде дать максимально подробный ответ. За старт можно взять к пример [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) ответ, вполне для понимания что и как.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, спасибо, ещё ситуация в том, что у меня все модели генерируются автоматически через Entity Framework и в них я вручную не могу менять что-то

Comment: Сама база является по сути Model слоем, сделайте обертку над ней, которая будет отдавать при помощи одного метода нужные данные, да и все. К примеру я в своем проекте тоже использую базу (правда LiteDB) и чтоб не писать постоянно `открыть базу, взять из таблицы значение такое, преобразовать его в тип такой`, я просто сделал удобные органы управления, которые сводятся к простому `var value = db.GetValue<string>("Key");` или `db.SetValue("Key", 123);`. В EF конечно будет по другому, но суть думаю вы уловили.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я прикрепил в вопросе скриншот того, как выглядит сгенерированная EF таблица, которая мне нужна, и получается логика такая, что мне нужно в отдельном классе например вытащить с неё нужные поля и уже с ними работать? Как же я туплю, пипец

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что это уже явно не относится к изначальному вопросу, верно? По правилам SO 1 вопрос, без изменения его сути. Возник еще вопрос, оформляйте его, задавайте) По поводу базы, обычно делают так: Некий основной орган управления базой, который позволяет обратиться к таблице, записать значение и так далее, далее класс, который отвечает за определенную логику.

Comment: Допустим, "человек", вот у вас класс `class Person {}`, он должен к примеру получить выписку счета из базы. Передаете класс базы через конструктор и делаете методы получения значений (`class Person { private DataBase Base; public Person(DataBase base) => Base = base; public int Id {get;}  public int Balance => Base.Persons.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == Id); }`) и уже дальше этот класс используется где надо (`new Person(DataBase).Balance;`). Это так, пример на коленке, но должно думаю хватить для понимания. А и да, не используйте русские названия в переменных! Ну не красиво это...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всё, понял, спасибо огромное, а по поводу русских названий я полностью согласен, но БД не моя, от других людей, не могу там что-то менять

Comment: Ну так для этого есть специальные атрибуты, например `[Column("Title")]`, где `Title` - это как зовется в базе, а само свойство уже зовете так, как положено.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял