# Динамическое создание кнопок со вложенными TextBox'ами WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Задача следующая: нужно сделать список кликабельных элементов, выглядеть должно так:
[*клик*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFTmx.png)

В WPF новичок, придумал следующее решение:
Все эти элементы хочу сделать кнопками, для этого прописал стиль:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="req_bt">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="729"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="76"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Width="729" Height="76" Fill="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Номер обращения" FontFamily="20" Foreground="#999999" Width="180" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="inc" IsReadOnly="True" Width="209" Height="32" FontFamily="Roboto" Text="INC1234_123456" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,36,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="descr" IsReadOnly="True" Width="392" Height="76" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="273,0,0,0" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="LOL"/>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/Mask.png" Width="19.73" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Выглядит это дело нормально, но вопрос: как получить доступ к TextBox'ам, чтобы менять в них текст?

Comment: Сами что пробовали? Ведь это основа основ, поймите как работают привязки, сделайте `<ItemsSouce>` в XAML и привяжите его к коллекции классов, где каждый класс будет содержать нужные данные для кнопки. Даже тут на SO есть кучу примеров на эту тему, не уж то даже поискать нет желания?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Желание поискать есть, но нет понимания, в какую сторону копать. Пошел гуглить привязки:)

Comment: [Подсказка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1120716/373567). [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). [Еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю поможет эта статья про ItemTemplate в ListBox:
https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.3.php