# Списочный элемент управления без выделения

Tags: wpf, xaml

Нужно вывести список элементов с текстовыми полями для дальнейшей работы с введенными данными. Выглядеть это должно таким образом:

[image: Список элементов]

Сейчас это сделано через ListBox с использованием ItemTemplate, но мне не нужна возможность выделять элементы.
Каким образом это можно сделать, не используя ListBox? Или, может, есть способ запретить выделение?

XAML-код:

```
<GroupBox Padding="0 10 0 0" Header="W" Grid.Column="2">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Widths}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="W1 = "/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="70" MaxHeight="20"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="mm"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Возьмите что-то более базового уровня, например `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1120716/373567) это делается. По сути просто замените `ListBox` на `ItemsControl`