# DependencyProperty в пользовательском элементе управления не работает

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Noveno.Common.CheckEdit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Noveno.Common"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="5 1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="chkCatPitch" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Margin="5 0"/>
        </CheckBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="edtData" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Для того чтобы как то натянуть на него модель ему нужны `DependencyProperty`, посему:

```
public partial class CheckEdit : UserControl, ICheckControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckedDP", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckEdit));
    public static DependencyProperty EditTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EditTextDP", typeof(string), typeof(CheckEdit));
    public string Caption
    {            
        get
        {
            return chkCatPitch.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            chkCatPitch.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public string EditText
    {
        get
        {
            return edtData.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            edtData.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)chkBox.IsChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            chkBox.IsChecked = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsCheckedDP
    {
        get
        {
            PropertyGet();
            return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
            PropertySet();
        }
    }
    public string EditTextdDP
    {
        get
        {
            PropertyGet();
            return (string)GetValue(EditTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(EditTextProperty, value);
            PropertySet();
        }
    }
    private void PropertySet()
    {
        chkBox.IsChecked = (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        edtData.Text = (string)GetValue(EditTextProperty);
    }
    private void PropertyGet()
    {
        SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, chkBox.IsChecked);
        SetValue(EditTextProperty, edtData.Text);
    }
    public CheckEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Но вот эти самые DependencyProperty не работают, ни в дизайне, ни в рантайме, и модель, судя по всему, на них не натягивается. Смотрел через отладку, свойства даже не отрабатывают. Словно их нет, или ничего в них не написано.

```
<common:CheckEdit Caption="Исполнитель" IsCheckedDP="True"/>
```

IsCheckedDP должен устанавливать состояние CheckBox. Но ничего не происходит ни в дизайнере, ни при запуске.

Мне по факту вроде как необходимо использовать еще более сложные кастомные элементы, но проблема скорее всего в том что я не могу привязать адекватно свойства с которыми бы работала модель.

Comment: А привязки где? Почему все через имена объектов?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не имею ни малейшего понятия о чем речь. Гайды молчат об этом или не прозрачны, или не полны. Как должно быть?

Comment: Ну вы что, примеров уйма, прям здесь пишите `UserControl` и получайте кучу примеров с реализацией. У вас должно быть не `x:Name="edtData"`, а `Text = "{Binding Text, ElementName=uc}"`, где `uc` - это указанное имя самого окна, без этого источник данных у контрола будет браться не от туда. Вон я например [делал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553) кнопки (правда там стиль, но все же).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, наверное, со связями. По крайней мере, работает.

1. Необходимо в шапке UserControl дать условное имя своему кастомному элементу.
   Например, `x:Name="Elm"`
2. Необходимо определить правильно DependencyProperty и зарегистрировать их в коде элемента.
3. Необходимо привязать свойства в xaml элемента. Например `Text = "{Binding Text, ElementName=Elm}`