# Почему возникает ошибка: XDG0062 "The resource "Img" could not be resolved". В моем проекте на wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть шаблон для кнопок бокового меню, и я хочу добавить на кнопку иконку.
Вот мой ControlTemplate^

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SlideMenuButtons" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid x:Name="Btn" Height="45">
            <Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey = Img}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

А вот сама кнопка в StackPannel:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SlideMenuButtons}" Click="Button_Click"
                    Content="КНОПКА">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <ImageSource x:Key="Img">res/icons/personal_card.png</ImageSource>
                </Button.Resources>
        </StackPanel>
```

Если я правильно понял суть ошибки, то шаблон не сопоставляет имя ресурса Img c ключом x:Key="Img" в ImageSource.

Я уже прочитал множество информации по этой ошибке и чаще всего советуют закрыть-удалить в корне программы .vs-открыть проект и пересобрать.
Не помогает, изменить имя пути к файлу тоже. Что ещё можно попробовать?

Comment: Не тем вы занимаетесь. 1. Картинки, в 22 году, это уже как-то плохо, ибо их полностью вытеснили векторы, которые и при масштабировании не теряют качество, и место занимают в разы меньше. 2. Иконка для кнопки - это не задача стиля, а задача контрола. Сделайте свой контрол, в котором будет свойство `Icon` например, а дальше просто пишите `<MyButton Icon = "..." />`. Вот, почитайте допустим [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553), по аналогии сможете сделать нужное вам. Ну а про ошибку, мне кажется тут дело в том, что нет ресурса `Img` до создания кнопки. Сделайте его глобальным.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй обновить XAML через кнопку обновить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]