# Не отображаются данные в userControl. Master-Detail.Master-List. Detail-UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Используется Master-Detail:

- Master-List;
- Detail-UserControl.

Я пробую использовать ListBox.
А у него проблемы с командами...

**Вопросы.**
**1.** Как ListBox применить для работы с командами?

или

**2.** Что удобнее использовать взамен ListBox для отображения списка и передачи Item в UserControl?
Чтобы можно было просто список отобразить или(и) список с кнопками, иконками...

---

https://github.com/jhon65496/MasterDetailApp01

**Pic-1**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Pic-2**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
 
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }
 
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }
 
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
}
```

**Базовый ViewModel.cs**

```
internal abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));            
            }
     
            protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
            {
                if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
                field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
                return true;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
            }
     
            private bool _Disposed;
            protected virtual void Dispose(bool Disposing)
            {
                if(!Disposing || _Disposed) return;
                _Disposed = true;
                // Освобождение управляемых ресурсов
            }
}
```

---

### MainWindow

#### View

##### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="GroupsStudents01.Views.Windows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupsStudents01.Views.Windows"
        xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:GroupsStudents01.ViewModels"
        
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        
        Height="450" Width="800">
 
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>        
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>-->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="Группы">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 SelectedIndex="10"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Группа. Детали">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentModel}"/>
            </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

#### ViewModel

##### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; }
               
        #region SelectedGroup
        private Group _SelectedGroup;
        
        public Group SelectedGroup
        {
            get => _SelectedGroup;
            set => Set(ref _SelectedGroup, value);        
        }
        #endregion
 
        #region Заголовок окна. Для теста подключения View + ViewModel
        private string _Title = "Группы-Студенты";
 
        /// <summary>Заголовок окна</summary>
        public string Title
        {
            get => _Title;            
            set => Set(ref _Title, value);
        }
 
        #endregion
 
        #region CurrentModel : ViewModel - Текущая дочерняя модель-представления
 
        /// <summary>Текущая дочерняя модель-представления</summary>
        private ViewModel _CurrentModel;
 
        /// <summary>Текущая дочерняя модель-представления</summary>
        public ViewModel CurrentModel { get => _CurrentModel; private set => Set(ref _CurrentModel, value); }
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Command ShowGroupDetailViewCommand - Отобразить представление группы
        private RelayCommand showGroupDetailViewCommand;
        public RelayCommand ShowGroupDetailViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return showGroupDetailViewCommand ??
                  (showGroupDetailViewCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                  {
                      // Group group = obj as _SelectedGroup;
                      CurrentModel = new GroupDetailViewModel(SelectedGroup);
                  }));
            }
        }
        #endregion
 
        /* ---------------------------------- */
        #region Конструктор        
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            var groups = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => new Group
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = $"Группа {i}",
                Description = $"Description {i}",
            });
 
            Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(groups);        
        }
        #endregion
        /* ---------------------------------- */
 
    }
```

---

### GroupDetail

#### View

##### GroupDetailView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="GroupsStudents01.Views.GroupDetailView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupsStudents01.Views"             
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GroupsStudents01.ViewModels"             
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:GroupDetailViewModel/>        
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Header="Информация" DataContext="{Binding Group}">
            <DockPanel>
                <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Rows="1" Margin="-3,3">
                    <Button Foreground="Green" Padding="0,5" Margin="3,0"
            Command="{Binding CreateNewStudentCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedGroup}"/>
                    <Button Foreground="Blue" Padding="0,5" Margin="3,0"
            Command="{Binding EditStudentCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedStudent}"/>
                </UniformGrid>
                <Grid Margin="3" DataContext="{Binding Book}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Id:"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Category:"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Name:"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Description:"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="Дата рождения:"/>
 
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Description}"/>                   
 
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**GroupDetailViewModel.cs**

```
 internal class GroupDetailViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        #region Group
        private Group _group;
 
        public Group Group
        {
            get => _group;
            set => Set(ref _group, value);
        }
        #endregion
 
        public GroupDetailViewModel(Group group)
        {
            _group = group;
        }
    }
```

---

### Model

##### Group.cs

```
internal class Group 
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

### **Обновление-1**

Под **Master-Detail** понимаю следующую компоновку.(см. картинку)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553
В примере отображение **Detail** осуществляется в `StackPanel` (если я правильно понял).

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/Autor}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/DateTime}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Моя цель отобразить **Detail** в отдельном `UserControl`, который вписан в **MainWindow.xaml**.
Пример моей попытки реализовать решение...

```
 <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Группа. Детали">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentModel}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

---

---

## Обновление-2

### Решение-1. Полуработает.

Проект с изменениями.
[github.com--MasterDetailApp01](https://github.com/jhon65496/MasterDetailApp01/tree/answ01)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Выполнено

Создал словарь **ModelMainView.xaml**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupDetailViewModel}">
    <view:GroupDetailView DataContext="{Binding Group}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Прописал словарь **ModelMainView.xaml** в **App.xaml**

```xml
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates/ModelMainView.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>         
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**
Создал метод

```cs
private void OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted()
{   
  CurrentModel = new GroupDetailViewModel(SelectedGroup);
}
```

Добавил метод `OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted()` в свойство `SelectedGroup`

```cs
#region SelectedGroup
private Group _SelectedGroup;

public Group SelectedGroup
{
    get => _SelectedGroup;
    set
    {
        Set(ref _SelectedGroup, value);
        OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted();
    }
    
}
#endregion
```

Создал команду `ShowGroupDetailViewCommand2`на случай вызова нового представления кнопкой.

```cs
private RelayCommand showGroupDetailViewCommand2;
public RelayCommand ShowGroupDetailViewCommand2
{
    get
    {
        return showGroupDetailViewCommand2 ??
        (showGroupDetailViewCommand2 = new RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted();
        }));
    }
}
```

### Примечания

В словаре **ModelMainView.xaml**

1. Если изменить `DataContext`как показано ниже, **GroupDetailView** не видит **GroupDetailViewModel**

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupDetailViewModel}">
    <view:GroupDetailView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

2. Если изменить `DataContext`как показано ниже, **GroupDetailView** не видит **GroupDetailViewModel**

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupDetailViewModel}">
    <view:GroupDetailView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Вопрос

1. Как сделать чтобы **GroupDetailView** видел **GroupDetailViewModel**?
   Чтобы там(в **GroupDetailViewModel**) можно было размещать команды с параметрами и т.д.
   Напомню, что сейчас **GroupDetailView** видит только свойство `Group`

---

Т.е. я ожидаю сделать в **ModelMainView.xaml**

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupDetailViewModel}">
    <view:GroupDetailView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Сейчас в **ModelMainView.xaml** DataContext выглядит `DataContext="{Binding Group}"`
А я в примерах вижу

- `<view:GroupDetailView DataContext="{Binding}"/>`
  или
- `<view:GroupDetailView/>`
  В моём случае **DataContext** из примеров не приводит к нужному результату.

Потом в **GroupDetailView.xaml**
В `GroupBox` пропишу `DataContext` типа

```xml
<GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Header="Информация" DataContext="{Binding Grouop}">
```

А дальше в дочерних полях прибиндю свойства Группы.

---

## Обновление-3

https://github.com/jhon65496/MasterDetailApp01/tree/answ02

#### GroupDetailViewModel.cs

```cs
internal class GroupDetailViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set => Set(ref id, value);
    }


    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }


    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set => Set(ref description, value);
    }

    
    public GroupDetailViewModel()
    {
        
    }
}
```

#### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```cs
public ObservableCollection<GroupDetailViewModel> Groups { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<GroupDetailViewModel> LoadData2()
{
    var groups = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(
        i => new GroupDetailViewModel
        {
            Id = i,
            Name = $"Группа {i}",
            Description = $"Description {i}"
        });

    return groups;    
}

#region Конструктор        
public MainWindowViewModel()
{            
    Groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupDetailViewModel>(LoadData2());
}
#endregion

#region SelectedGroup2
private GroupDetailViewModel _SelectedGroup2;

public GroupDetailViewModel SelectedGroup2
{
    get => _SelectedGroup2;
    set
    {
        Set(ref _SelectedGroup2, value);

        OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted2(value);
    }
}
#endregion

private void OnShowGroupDetailViewCommandExecuted2(GroupDetailViewModel selectedGroup)
{
    CurrentModel = selectedGroup;
}
```

#### ModelMainView.xaml

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupDetailViewModel}">
   <view:GroupDetailView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

### Вопрос

В **GroupDetailView.xaml** не работает биндинг.
В чём проблема?

---

## Обновление-4

По материалам **Обновление-4**.
https://github.com/jhon65496/MasterDetailApp01/tree/answ02
В **GroupDetailView.xaml** - `<GroupBox>` - удалено: `DataContext="{Binding Grouop}"`
Решение работает.

**Картинка-1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не смотря на то, что приложение запускается  **GroupDetailView.xaml**  в конструкторе выдаёт ошибки биндинга.

#### Вопрос.

1. Почему в **GroupDetailView.xaml** в конструкторе ошибки биндинга?
2. Код выполнен правильно?

**Примечание.**
Я закрывал/открывал **GroupDetailView.xaml**, **Решение**, **VisualStudio**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыли метку c#. Также много лишнего написали, к примеру, что за `Master-Detail`? По вопросу: Всякие `<Window.DataContext>` - [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). "Передать данные в контрол" - делайте `DependencyProperty` и через него устанавливайте все, что хотите. "Как вывести подробности" - при помощи [синхронизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553). "что я делаю не так?" - устанавливаете лишние `DataContext`, а также я не вижу, где используется `GroupDetailView`, ибо я так понимаю это вид контента, ок, тогда где `DataTemplate` с указанием типа и вида?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ **1.** `что за **Master-Detail**?` см. **Обновление-1**. 
**2.** Остальную представленную вами информацию перевариваю... Буду признателен, если продемонстрируете решение на моём или  другом более правильном примере...  Если у вас есть возможность...

Comment: `который вписан в MainWindow.xaml` - я не вижу этого, где хоть одно использование данного контрола? `осуществляется в StackPanel` - без разницы где вы будете это использовать. Ну вот допустим самое простое: 1. Убираем `<UserControl.DataContext>`. 2. Задаем вид контенту в ресурсах окна/контрола/приложения, получаем [примерно такое](https://pastebin.com/F7Rc0U3T). 3. Устанавливаем `ListBox` свойство `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. 4. Задаем контенту тоже самое свойство, что и `ListBox`, но со слешем в конце (`Content="{Binding Groups/}"`). Все, вам автоматом WPF проставит все нужное.

Comment: Другое вариант (как по мне более правильный) - отказаться от `ContentControl` и использовать контрол напрямую. Тут либо 1. Указывать ему `DataContext` (`<local:GroupDetailView DataContext = "{Binding Groups/}"/>`) 2. Задать ему `DependencyProperty` и заполнять их. Сами DP делаются просто, пишем в студии `propdp`и жмем TAB, правим немного XAML, готово ([как пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553)). Ну а использование тогда будет такое `<local:GroupDetailView GroupId = "{Binding Groups/Id}" GroupName = "{Binding Groups/Name}" />`, ну и так каждое нужное свойство.

Comment: Я вам уже все нужное дал, чего вы еще от меня хотите?) Даже пошаговую инструкцию дал одного из вариантов, дал ссылки на подробные ответы, где я подробно говорил о конкретном аспекте. Изучайте, возникнут вопросы, пишите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Извините, можно ещё чуток подсказку? **1.** См. **Обновление-2** **2.** Как сделать чтобы GroupDetailView видел GroupDetailViewModel?
Чтобы там(в GroupDetailViewModel) можно было размещать команды с параметрами

Comment: Что-то я не заметил сразу то, что вы выводите на экран модель (Group), а не как положено ViewModel. Когда вы устанавливаете через `DataTemplate` нужный вид объекту, за вас WPF автоматически задает `DataContext`, вам не надо его прописывать вручную. Контекстом будет являться сам объект. Что касается `GroupDetailViewModel`, то он у вас должен быть изначально в выводимой коллекции `ObservableCollection<GroupDetailViewModel> Groups`, ибо это по сути VM класс `Group` (Model). Модель очень редко напрямую выводят на экран, обычно получают модель, и на ее основе создают VM, которая и выводится.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ **1.** Я правильно вас понял? (см. **Обновление-3**). У меня чего-то не работает. ЮзерКонтрол в деталях отображает, а данных в ЮзерКонтроле нет..  **2.** В **GroupDetailView.xaml** не работает биндинг.
В чём проблема? **3.** Сам код правильный?

Comment: "В GroupDetailView.xaml не работает биндинг" - наверно потому, что вы не услышали про то, что "вам контекст ставит сам WPF", а вы игнорируя это делаете `DataContext="{Binding Grouop}"`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ **1.** Виноват. Исправил. Работает. см. **Обновление-4**. **2.** Но в конструкторе в **GroupDetailView.xaml** всё равно ошибка биндинга... Но приложение запускается..

Comment: Это не ошибка биндинга, а просто так отображает студия данные, о которых ничего не знает. Подобное не влияет на проект. Если всеж хотите, чтоб студия знала о свойствах, предлагала вам их, и так далее, то согласитесь с тем, что на скрине, она установит `d:DataContext` - это контекст только для дизайнера, не для программы. А вообще, советую запустить проект, и работать в живую, не смотря на то, что в конструкторе.